# Android Wi-Fi: 'Address family not supported'

Tags: android, wifi

I am making an application which makes use of the internet.

It works fine when the Wi-Fi is availble. But when the Wi-Fi is turned off, it gives me an error: "Address family not supported".

I am using the `NetworkInfo` Class to know, if the network is available. Im using WifiManager to enable and manage Wi-fi connection if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the following code to check if a network is available:

```
ConnectivityManager mConnectivity = (ConnectivityManager) this
                                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = mConnectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (info == null) {
    // No inet
}
```

Comment: Thanks for guide.can i make explicit connection from my application?any idea

Comment: @rakesh-gondaliya: What you mean by "explicit connection"?

Comment: there might be settings in mobile in which it might be the case that GPRS may be the Default connection, so if Wi-Fi is available i want to make Http connection which uses Wifi only, so that i would not be charged for the transfer of packets through GPRS. Did u get?

Comment: @rakesh-gondaliya: Yes. I am not 100% sure but I think there is only one type of connection at certain time. NetworkInfo should tell you which is available.